# Title separator issue wordpress

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I am using Yoast seo. I am having issue with the title separator. Please help me to know where on Wordpress or Yoast seo editor I can rectify this?

Issue example

Title name- Sitename (Dash (-) sign is not having space)

Thanks.

Comment: You are seeing issue on homepage or all pages?

Comment: Hi Charan, On all the pages.

Comment: My theme has issue with yoast so, the functions were customized. And, the category and sub-category page don't have snippet option and get it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

click and edit a page or post

You can find the snippet editor in the Yoast SEO meta box, which is located under the main content block of your post or page.

If you click on ‘Edit snippet’ the snippet editor will open so you can change the title, slug and meta description